# Salesforce Bulk Upsert throws Duplicate error

Tags: salesforce, upsert, salesforce-lightning, rest

I am doing the R&D on the duplicate error scenario in SF Bulk API and found that somehow I am not able to perform insert and update operation simultaneously for the contact with the same(external id) within the single batch.

I received a duplicate error. Screen capture for reference

https://www.screencast.com/t/ReE41vuzb

When the batch contains different external id's I do not have any error. But when external Id is repeated in a single batch I receive the below error. 
{
  "success" : false,
  "created" : false,
  "id" : null,
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "Duplicate external id specified: 7401",
    "fields" : [ "Origami_ID__c" ],
    "statusCode" : "DUPLICATE_VALUE",
    "extendedErrorDetails" : null
  }

Although there is No duplicate at the target side.

Comment: What is the reason you have 'duplicates' within the same batch? Also is there a reason you cannot avoid this situation? I do not have a solution, but this could be a documented feature. This article is using PATCH, but perhaps te same underlying concept. 
Please refer to the below link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318436&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Comment: We have a file with 30K records which we split into 5K batch size use Bulk Upsert Operation. We can expect that file may contain records with duplicates where the record details can change from 1st records to nth records. As of now, we are filtering just to pick the last unique record. But Ideally, if a job has 5k records with duplicate records for same unique ID, the first records should be inserted and subsequent records should be update rather then throwing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the last record from multiple records with same unique id.

For this follow the below logic:

```
//Create Map and populate the map with last record having unique id
Map<String,MyObject__c> mapWithUniqueIdMyObject = new Map<String,MyObject__c>();
MyObject__c currentObject;
for(Integer currentPosition = myObjectListWith5000Records.size(); currentPosition >=0 ;currentPosition--){
     currentObject = myObjectListWith5000Records.get( currentPosition );
     if( !mapWithUniqueIdMyObject.containsKey(currentObject.Origami_ID__c) ){//If the map does not contain any object with unique id then put the object in the map
          mapWithUniqueIdMyObject.put( currentObject.Origami_ID__c, currentObject );
     }
} 
upsert mapWithUniqueIdMyObject.getValues();
```